# Logistic distribution's minimal sufficient statistics

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, sufficient-statistics, logistic-distribution

Distribution function (pdf) is
$$f(x|\theta) = \frac{e^{-x-\theta}}{(1+e^{-(x-\theta)})^2},~-\infty<x<\infty,~-\infty<\theta<\infty$$

If $x$ is sample from population, $f(x|\theta)$ is

$$ f(x|\theta) = e^{-n\bar x+n\theta}\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\left(1+e^{-(x_i-\theta)}\right)^2}.$$

I calculated $f(x|\theta)/f(y|\theta),$ but  how can I find minimal sufficient statistics?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3168804/321264.

Comment: It's because there is none.

Comment: Or rather, the ordered vector of observations is minimal sufficient.

Comment: Oh thank you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

For the logistic distribution, there is no useful sufficient reduction. Another way of saying so, is that the order statistics are the minimal sufficient statistic. For a proof, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3168804/prove-the-order-statistic-is-a-minimal-sufficient-statistic-for-the-logistic-pdf

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Kjetil Halvorsen's point, it's worth noting that the maximum likelihood estimate (MAP for Bayes) is *asymptotically* a sufficient statistic. The amount of information not included in the MLE will be negligible for large sample sizes.

The Hodges-Lehmann estimator for the location is also asymptotically a sufficient statistic, but only if the scale is known a priori.